# Is there any way to use variable name in API testing in Postman?

Tags: rest, api, postman, web-api-testing

I'm testing the API using postman (new to the api testing and has just started to test it), it was previously working as I use the variable name it stops working and displaying source code instead of the result.

Previously I'm using this API: https://reqres.in/api/users/2
After referring it to the variable it is now: `{{url}}/api/users/2`

Previously it is showing me result like this:

```
{
    "page": 2,
    "per_page": 3,
    "total": 12,
    "total_pages": 4,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "first_name": "Eve",
            "last_name": "Holt",
            "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/marcoramires/128.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "first_name": "Charles",
            "last_name": "Morris",
            "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/stephenmoon/128.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "first_name": "Tracey",
            "last_name": "Ramos",
            "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/bigmancho/128.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you post an image of what you're seeing in Postman? What's the status code returned? Is this a GET / POST / something else. More details will help people to help you.

Comment: @Div No environment variable is set, I have set the variable in the collection by clicking on the edit option and then selecting variables. images link  https://imgur.com/hY8nLDr   https://imgur.com/CyqDONY

Comment: @Danny Dainton  image link:  https://imgur.com/CyqDONY,  https://imgur.com/hY8nLDr

Comment: @surenderpal: you can add environment variable as shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2QZf.gif

Comment: @Div You should add that as an answer rather than a comment. It's a good .gif that demonstrates adding variables. Nice one.

Comment: Thanks! @DannyDainton, I was not sure as OP haven't confirmed yet though, answer added.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that, beforehand, your Environment Variable was set, presently it isn't. Simply select the Environment right upper corner or include required value if its not present.

Here are the steps:

[image]

Good reads: [Postman Variables](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/environments_and_globals/variables/)